# Manage ui-router state history

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

In my single page app, I need to keep a state history to make it easier to navigate back and forth between states.  I have my own forward and back buttons that I'm using on my pages and not going through the browser's buttons.

This is the following code I have which uses the service I've created to store the states in an array.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
    StateMgmtService.add(toState, toParams);
});
```

In the service, I have something to the effect of the following:

```
var history = [];

    return {
        previous: function () {
            if (history && history.length > 0) {
                return history[history.length - 1];
            }
        },
        add: function (state, params) {
            var historyItem = {
                state: state,
                parameters: params
            };

            history.push(historyItem);
        }
    };
```

The problem is that any time I go back to a prior state, the stateChangeStart is fired which basically pollutes my history.  Consider the following example:

- starting from state a to b - b gets added to the history
- b to c - c gets added
- c back to b - b gets added again

This results in an endless looping of going from b to c to b to c...  So I basically need to not allow prior items to be added to the history or to somehow know that it's going back in the history, but stateChangeStart doesn't allow any differentiation as such.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the service, I ended up adding a goBack method that is to be called when wanting to traverse the history.  This function sets a flag indicating moving back in the history.  Then when the stateChangeStart event is fired and adds to the array, the service knows that it's an item that doesn't need to be added, resets the flag, and returns out of it. It's working out well so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it by validate the history(length-2) is equal with current state.
some code like this, on the service:

```
add: function(state, params) {
  var isBackState = function (currentState, listState) {
    var listStateLength = listState.length;
    if (listState[listStateLength -2].state === currentState) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  };

  if (history.length > 1 && isBackState(state, history) {
    return;
  }

  var historyItem = {
    state: state,
    parameters: params
  };

  history.push(historyItem);
}
```

if you only want the historyItem push into history if the previous state not equal with current state then you could add validation on $stateChangeStart function scope.

```
$rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
  if (toState === fromState) {
    return;
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: In my current app, it's possible to be on the same state just with different parameters.  For example,
/page/2
/page/3
So 'page' is the state and 2 and 3 are the parameters.  So it'd have to compare the state and parameters which seems somewhat unnecessary.

Comment: if you only want the historyItem push into history if the previous state not equal with current state then you could add validation on $stateChangeStart function scope.
$rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
if (toState === fromState) {
return;
}